# why is my shiny app crashing when implementing future::plan()?

Tags: r, shiny, crash

I'm developing a shiny app for my company, there is a expensive calculations and so i tried to use the future and promise packages for some async programing but the app crashes when future::plan(future::multiprocess) was added. i've been searching about the Qt5WebEngineCore.dll module but it seems to be just fine.
Sorry about the formatting, im new at SO

MRE: crashes at "plan(multiprocess)"

```
    library(shiny)
    library(promises)
    library(future)
    library(fst)
    library(data.table)
    library(DT)
    plan(multiprocess)

    write_fst(data.table(a=1:100,b=101:200),"dt.fst")
    ui=fluidPage(
      DTOutput("dt_example"),
      DTOutput("dt_example2")
    )
    server=function(input,output,session){
      dtreact% head()}
        )
      })
      output$dt_example=renderDT({datatable(dtreact() %...>% 
                                           (function(result){
                                             result[,lapply(.SD,sum)]}))},
                                            editable = T,
                                            rownames = F)
      output$dt_example2=renderDT({datatable(dtreact2() %...>% 
                                           (function(result){
                                             result[,lapply(.SD,sum)]}))},
                                            editable = T,
                                            rownames = F)
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

in the rstudio console and the R session is aborted with a fatal error, 
whereas:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(promises)
    library(future)
    library(fst)
    library(data.table)
    library(DT)

    write_fst(data.table(a=1:100,b=101:200),"dt.fst")
    ui<-fluidPage(
      DTOutput("dt_example"),
      DTOutput("dt_example2")
    )
    server<-function(input,output,session){
      dtreact<-reactive({
        read_fst("dt.fst",as.data.table = T)
      })
      dtreact2<-reactive({
        read_fst("dt.fst",as.data.table = T) %>% head()
      })
      output$dt_example<-renderDT({data.table(dtreact()[,lapply(.SD,sum)])},
                                   editable = T,
                                   rownames = F)
      output$dt_example2<-renderDT({data.table(dtreact2()[,lapply(.SD,sum)])},
                                             editable = T,
                                             rownames = F)
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

works fine

sessioninfo():

```
    R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

    Matrix products: default

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
    [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
     [1] data.table_1.12.8    fst_0.9.2            magrittr_1.5        
     [4] forcats_0.5.0        DT_0.13              shinycssloaders_0.3 
     [7] shinydashboard_0.7.1 future_1.17.0        promises_1.1.0      
    [10] shiny_1.4.0.2       

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      xtable_1.8-4      R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.6      
     [5] fastmap_1.0.1     globals_0.12.5    tools_4.0.0       parallel_4.0.0   
     [9] htmltools_0.4.0   crosstalk_1.1.0.1 yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.25    
    [13] later_1.0.0       htmlwidgets_1.5.1 codetools_0.2-16  glue_1.4.1       
    [17] mime_0.9          compiler_4.0.0    jsonlite_1.6.1    httpuv_1.5.2     
    [21] listenv_0.8.0
```

rstdio stop working details:

```
    event problem name: APPCRASH
      app name: rstudio.exe
      app version:  1.2.5042.0
      app timestamp:    5e84cb43
      module with error:    Qt5WebEngineCore.dll
      module's version: 5.12.1.0
      module's error timestamp: 5c501124
      exception code:   80000003
      Desplazamiento de excepción:  0000000001553989
      OS version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
      Id. de configuración regional:    13322
      Información adicional 1:  9360
      Información adicional 2:  93603780ff0b949df91ad9deacaa71d1
      Información adicional 3:  4ca9
      Información adicional 4:  4ca92b7744c96285fdc2774b2308308b
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal working example of the shiny app that causes the crash?

Comment: Don't know how much help I can be. I use `plan(multiprocess)` on an instance of RStudio Connect and it does not crash. I also use it on my windows dev laptop (R but not RStudio) daily, and it does not crash. Granted, neither of those are in the RStudio IDE, so perhaps that's not much help to you, sorry.

Comment: As far as confidential data goes ... yes, I completely understand. However, I believe it is more encumbent on *you* to find a way to give us more context and usability than it is for *us* to guess what your shiny app might look like and how it might be doing things. I do not mean that to sound harsh (thought it might), and this is certainly not an *absolute* thing, but ... since there is no "contractual obligation" of supporting questions here, under-supported questions often languish unnecessarily. Good luck!

Comment: i've added a dummy example that ilustrate the problem, i've come to think it might be some issue with the security or config of the laptop, given that it's from the company and in my personal laptop the problem does not arise. thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: Now **that's** good context (the permissions part)! It sounds like this might be a bug-report to RStudio or `future`, not gracefully excepting an error.